# TextCtrl disappears after changing color and calling sizer.Layout

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have encountered a very strange problem in wxPython which I think is a bug. Essentially I have one TextCtrl which changes background color when I press the ctrl key (don't ask why). I then have another button that calls sizer.Layout() on the BoxSizer where the TextCtrl is stored. When I do this, the TextCtrl disappears (attains a zero width). It only happens if there is sufficient text in the TextCtrl, and only if I press ctrl+(other key). Here is the code:

```
import wx


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):


    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.frame = parent


        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)



        self.btn = wx.Button(self, label="TextCtrl disappears?")
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClick)

        self.txt=wx.TextCtrl(self,value="bunch of text goes here")
        self.txt.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.onType)

        self.sizer.Add(self.txt,0,wx.CENTER|wx.ALL,5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.btn,0,wx.CENTER|wx.ALL,5)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()  


    def onType(self,event):
        if event.GetKeyCode()==308:
            self.txt.SetBackgroundColour((100,255,255,255))
        else:
            event.Skip()



    def onClick(self,event):

        self.sizer.Layout()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="")
        panel = MyPanel(self)

        self.Fit()
        self.Show()


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame()

app.MainLoop()
```

Now, try to go to the TextCtrl and press for instance ctrl+a, and then press the button. Is this a bug? More importantly, what is the workaround? I guess that the TextCtrl changes one of its attributes that specifies its size or behaviour under Layout(), but I can not figure out which one is being changed.

edit:

I am using ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7.12 and wxpython version 3.0.2.0.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on windows (neither classic nor Phoenix). TextCtrl never disappears.

Comment: @JonathanLindgren, what version of python/wxpython? What OS? Also, what do you mean by saying "there is sufficient text in the TextCtrl"? How much is sufficient?

Comment: @Igor I am using ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7.12 and wxpython version 3.0.2.0. Sufficient seems to be so that it covers the whole TextCtrl, so eg what I wrote as the default in the TextCtrl is enough (depending on how much text there is, the size might change to other sizes as well, not necessarily 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever it is, it has been resolved in wxpython 4.
Ways to avoid the problem.

Give the `TextCtrl` a `size=(n,n)` value

and / or

Replace the `wx.CENTER` with a `wx.EXPAND` when adding to the sizer.

i.e.

```
self.txt=wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,value="bunch of text goes here",size=(50,20))

self.sizer.Add(self.txt,0,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL,5)
```

Finally, there must be something queer about your keyboard, because this should not happen using `EVT_KEY_DOWN` but with `EVT_KEY_UP`. I don't think that `EVT_KEY_DOWN` normally sees a Ctrl key. See https://www.wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.KeyEvent.html